# Class bean in application context for Cacheable annotation

Tags: java, spring, caching, ehcache

I'm using Spring 4.1.4 and Ehcache 2.9 and caching using the `@Cacheable` annotation.
I've noticed that every public class that has a method with this annotation must be referenced in

> applicationContext.xml

as follows

```
<bean class="com.example.web.Test"/>
```

this forces me to add every public class that i want to cache into the applicationContext.

Is there a way to overcome this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course `@Cacheable` works only for spring beans.

There are many ways to instantiate a spring bean, explicite xml configuration `<bean class="..."/>` is only one. An other way is to enable the component scan and annotate the class with `@Component` or `@Service` (or some other) annotations.

Comment: Thanks @Ralph, I've added `@Component` before the public class and the `import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;` also in the context xml i've inserted the `<context:component-scan base-package="x.z.z" />` but now i'm getting this exception from the Tomcat "Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener"

Comment: Rise a new question, containing the COMPLETE stacktrace, the relevant code fragment and the configuration!